# I still did not receive my student visa from the Portuguese embassy and my college starts in 9 days. What should I do? Please help

Tags: application-status

Hello all and I would appreciate your help!

I applied for a Portuguese student visa around 2-3 months ago to pursue my Masters in Portugal, but I still haven't received any response back from the embassy. (I have gotten the Schengen tourist visa before 3 times.)

My mother went to the embassy yesterday, and they told her that they sent the passport and all my documents to Portugal and the acceptance comes from Portugal and not from the local embassy.

My college starts in 9 days and I am already very scared because I will be pursuing my Masters studies and if I do not get the visa acceptance then all the plans I have made for the next 2 years will be ruined.

Any suggestions or help? Does anyone know if I can contact someone from Portugal who gives the visas and email them about my case? Because obviously, it is not the local embassy that gives the visas, as they explained that they already sent the documents to Portugal and the acceptance or rejection comes from there. They said that they can not do anything about it because it is out of their hands.

I am a Lebanese national also with São Tomé nationality, where I am now. I applied directly to the [Portuguese Embassy in São Tomé](https://www.saotome.embaixadaportugal.mne.pt/en/the-embassy/contact).

My application and its disposition appear to be stalled somewhere in the pipeline between here and the decision-making hub in Portugal, and the embassy here is unable to get definitive status information.

I need a way to either learn the status of my application or to elevate its priority. What can I do?

Comment: Did your father give you the receipt with the Schengen reference number on it?

Comment: Nope he did not! Should i ask him about it?